# python accessing variable from different module

Tags: python, variables, module, tkinter

I have 2 scripts. **Main.py** and **module1.py**.

## Module1.py

```
class classA():
    def method1(self):
        self.c=a+b
        ....
        ....
    def method2():
        ....
class classB():
    ....
class classC():
    ....
```

## Main.py

```
import module1
print module1.classA.c
```

I am trying to access the variable c from `module1.py` `classA` in the `main.py` But when i run main.py, it gave me error saying "c is not defined".What is the correct way to do it?
i have tried `_builtin_` as well but it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not call the function, thus `self.c` would never have been created. Also, create an instance of the class:

```
import module1
myinst = module1.classA()
myinst.method1()
print myinst.c
```